# Extracting SVG from Font Awesome

Tags: html, svg, font-awesome

I want to get the SVG path data from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) glyphs so that I can use them straight up as SVG in my HTML. I thought it would be as easy as copy-pasting the path data from [fontawesome-webfont.svg](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg), but when I use it in my HTML the symbols are all rendering upside-down. Anyone know why?

(See [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DBQQU/3/))

**Font Awesome SVG:**

```
<glyph unicode="&#xf007;" horiz-adv-x="1408" d="M1408 131q0 -120 -73 -189.5t-194 -69.5h-874q-121 0 -194 69.5t-73 189.5q0 53 3.5 103.5t14 109t26.5 108.5t43 97.5t62 81t85.5 53.5t111.5 20q9 0 42 -21.5t74.5 -48t108 -48t133.5 -21.5t133.5 21.5t108 48t74.5 48t42 21.5q61 0 111.5 -20t85.5 -53.5t62 -81 t43 -97.5t26.5 -108.5t14 -109t3.5 -103.5zM1088 1024q0 -159 -112.5 -271.5t-271.5 -112.5t-271.5 112.5t-112.5 271.5t112.5 271.5t271.5 112.5t271.5 -112.5t112.5 -271.5z" />
```

**... Ported to HTML SVG (and scaled down):**

```
<svg width="1000" height="1000" ><path transform="scale(0.1,0.1)" d="M1408 131q0 -120 -73 -189.5t-194 -69.5h-874q-121 0 -194 69.5t-73 189.5q0 53 3.5 103.5t14 109t26.5 108.5t43 97.5t62 81t85.5 53.5t111.5 20q9 0 42 -21.5t74.5 -48t108 -48t133.5 -21.5t133.5 21.5t108 48t74.5 48t42 21.5q61 0 111.5 -20t85.5 -53.5t62 -81 t43 -97.5t26.5 -108.5t14 -109t3.5 -103.5zM1088 1024q0 -159 -112.5 -271.5t-271.5 -112.5t-271.5 112.5t-112.5 271.5t112.5 271.5t271.5 112.5t271.5 -112.5t112.5 -271.5z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

All per the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/fonts.html#SVGFontsOverview)...

*Unlike standard graphics in SVG, where the initial coordinate system has the y-axis pointing downward, the design grid for SVG fonts, along with the initial coordinate system for the glyphs, has the y-axis pointing upward for consistency with accepted industry practice for many popular font formats.*

As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113478/extracting-svg-from-font-awesome#comment33532603_18113524), Changing the wrapper to `<svg height="179.2" width="179.2"><path transform="scale(0.1,-0.1) translate(0,-1536)" d="..." /></svg>` seems to do the trick,
where **1792** is the units-per-em and **1536** is the ascent on font-face element

Comment: For completeness of this answer, changing the wrapper to `<svg height="179.2" width="179.2"><path transform="scale(0.1,-0.1) translate(0,-1536)" d="..." /></svg>` seems to do the trick, where `1792` is the `units-per-em` and `1536` is the `ascent` on `font-face` element.

Comment: Re `1792 is the units-per-em`: Typo? I would think it would be `179.2` to match the height/width.

Answer (score 122):

*UPDATE 2022 thanks to Chris Aelbrecht comment below:*
official repo has the SVGs of the latest version for download

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/svgs

---

original answer:

Just get the ready svg icons from [this github repo](https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/tree/master/black/svg)
They are already flipped and centered as needed

[image]

Comment: I found a lot of these had icons that were cropped on the sides, for example car

Comment: Version 5 can be found here https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/svgs

Answer (score 23):

[IcoMoon app](https://icomoon.io) makes this dead simple.

Comment: IcoMoon is very easy to use, but I've found that it exports longer paths than the SVGs in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/tree/master/black/svg). Try for comparison the fa-gift icon. The `path` is 837 characters via IcoMoon, vs. [514 in the repo](https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG/blob/master/black/svg/gift.svg).

Answer (score 17):

Use fontforge script.  There is a script I found [online here](http://fontforge.10959.n7.nabble.com/Saving-glyphs-as-SVG-files-via-command-line-td12726.html):

```
fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); SelectWorthOutputting(); foreach Export("svg"); endloop;' font.ttf
```

See: 
http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/scripting.html

Answer (score 10):

You can just download any Font-Awesome svg you need from their repo at Github

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/svgs

Comment: Not the pro icons

Answer (score 9):

There is also a node.js tool that will automate this for you, & create a before & after `verify.html`.
https://github.com/eugene1g/font-blast

I've used it on other fonts, only 1 bad icon conversion so far, but rest in the font SVG was fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply download the latest version of `fa` here: https://fontawesome.com/

And then go to the `advanced-options/raw-svg` folder. There you will find three folders `brands`, `regular` and `solid` containing all the latest icons available.

Answer (score 2):

You can download them from flaticon.com here:

http://www.flaticon.com/packs/font-awesome

Comment: Can be helpful, but when you want to resize a path from 512x512 to 20x20, it requires a lot of scale-down button-mashing