# Rotating Font Awesome SVG paths

Tags: css, svg, font-awesome

I want to use Font Awesome icons in my application. Because every icon have to be rendered as the part of an existing SVG element, instead of using the webfonts I want to use the SVG paths.

Given that the design grid for SVG glyphs points upward, as explained here:
[Extracting SVG from Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113478/extracting-svg-from-font-awesome)

I understand why they are appearing upside down, the question is, how to rotate them properly. The only solution I found so far was to rotate the icons programmatically before placing them to the canvas:

```
var icon = require('icons/fa-copy');
...
el.transform("r180"); //Raphael
```

my question is, how can I achieve the same with css, for example `-webkit-transform`?

Applying this transformation on the `<path>` element which is containing the SVG path the icon was rotated **and** translated to (0, 0).

**EDIT**

Note that this is about rotating SVG path elements, see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NWXFn/

Comment: I haven't worked with SVG paths before, but can't you just rotate the SVG element with pure css? http://jsfiddle.net/NWXFn/1/

Comment: @nkmol that would rotate the whole canvas together with the other elements, I have to rotate the icon only. Try to apply your css transformations to `body > svg > path` and see what happens.

Comment: @nkmol finally, I was able to rotate it: http://jsfiddle.net/NWXFn/2/ but this isn't really a solution because this way, every icon should have it's own transformation matrix.

Comment: And way do you want to do this with pure css instead of doing it in the javascript element path?

Comment: Maintainability, simplicity, etc. This way I could just a create a CSS class `flip` which if applied on the icon will rotate it, and I can totally forget about rotating every single icon in javascript, applying that `flip` class to all of my icon instances will do that. But it seems a lot harder than I thought.