# Generate SVG image from icon font?

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts, icon-fonts

Is it possible to generate SVG images from icon fonts?

For instance, [framework7](https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-icons) offers many cool icons with the icon font below, but they only make SVG versions available for [1000 icons](https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-icons/tree/master/svg), leaving 230 without SVG equivalents.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Framework7 Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/Framework7Icons-Regular.eot");
  src: local('Framework7 Icons'),
     local('Framework7Icons-Regular'),
     url("../fonts/Framework7Icons-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
     url("../fonts/Framework7Icons-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
     url("../fonts/Framework7Icons-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}

.f7-icons, .framework7-icons {
  font-family: 'Framework7 Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga";
  font-feature-settings: "liga";
}
```

Comment: You can check this, maybe an answer for your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196884/how-to-render-fontawesome-as-svg-image-using-javascript

Comment: See also ["How to convert font icon to .svg by myself?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187756/how-to-convert-font-icon-to-svg-by-myself)