# How to convert font icon to .svg by myself?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, font-awesome

How to get an icon from font? Or convert font icon to .svg. I more interest in process (not third-party services)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Why do you need this? I thinks it's not that correct for icons font providers

Comment: Not sure about extracting it from a front file, but you could try printing the character on a js canvas, and that could let you export the canvas (with the character on it) as a PNG file. You could feed this file into a vectorizor (I'm sure there's a command line program to do it) to convert it into an SVG.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, what I did was to install the font locally and then go into Character Map and find the symbol I'm looking for.
Then I copied and went into Illustrator and created an empty text box, pasted the symbol and then selected the icon font.

Then I just right clicked and converted to outline and exported to SVG.

If you don't have Illustrator, try doing the same thing within Inkscape (it's free).

Comment: I use CorelDraw. Like CptKicks said, I installed the TTF version of the icon-font on Windows, than opened CorelDraw and used the Symbol option (Ctrl+F11) which allows to visualize all characters in a font and drag drop that onto the canvas. From there you export as SVG. I guess you can do the same with Inkscape which is free.

Answer (score 3):

### Parse icon fonts with [opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js)

If your icon library does not provide a svg icon collection, you can parse and convert any font glyph using opentype.js.

Once you've parsed the font file, you can loop through all available glyphs and create an svg `<path>` output via `Glyph.getPath(x, y, fontSize)` method.

### Example: generate spritesheet from font file

```js
let fontFile = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2";

// init
loadFont(fontFile, processFont);

//default
let params = {
  fontSize: 100,
  decimals: 2
};

// process font file after loading and parsing
function processFont(font) {
  showGlyphs(font, params)
}


// create svg sprites from font glyphs
function showGlyphs(font, params) {
  // sanitize font name
  let fontFamily = font.tables.name.fontFamily.en.replaceAll(' ', '_').replaceAll('.', '_');
  let unitsPerEm = font.unitsPerEm;
  let ratio = params.fontSize / unitsPerEm;
  let ascender = font.ascender;
  let descender = Math.abs(font.descender);
  let lineHeight = (ascender + descender) * ratio;
  let baseline = +((100 / (ascender + descender)) * descender).toFixed(3) + 2;

  let decimals = params.decimals;
  let glyphs = font.glyphs.glyphs;
  let keys = Object.keys(glyphs).length;
  let htmlOutput = '';
  let useMarkup = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
    let glyph = glyphs[i];
    let lineHeight = (ascender + descender) * ratio;
    let leftSB = glyph.leftSideBearing * ratio;
    let rightSB = (glyph.advanceWidth - glyph.xMax) * ratio;
    let glyphW = (glyph.advanceWidth) * ratio;
    let poxX = 0;

    // adjust negative widths
    if ((glyph.advanceWidth + leftSB) < 0) {
      glyphW = Math.abs(leftSB) + Math.abs(glyph.advanceWidth) + Math.abs(rightSB);
      poxX = Math.abs(leftSB);
    }

    // get svg path data
    let path = glyph.getPath(
      poxX,
      ascender * ratio,
      params.fontSize
    ).toSVG(decimals);


    if (Object.hasOwn(glyph, 'points')) {
      // add symbol definitions
      htmlOutput += `<symbol id="symbol_${glyph.name}" data-id="${glyph.index}" viewBox="0 0 ${+(glyphW).toFixed(2)} ${+(lineHeight).toFixed(2)}"> ${path}</symbol>`;

      // add visible <use> instances
      useMarkup += `<svg id="use_wrap_${glyph.name}"  viewBox="0 0 ${+(glyphW).toFixed(2)} ${+(lineHeight).toFixed(2)}"><use href="#symbol_${glyph.name}" /></svg>`;
    }
  }

  // add hidden svg sprite
  htmlOutput = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="sprite_${fontFamily}" style="width:0; height:0; position:absolute; overflow:hidden;">` + htmlOutput + `</svg>` + useMarkup;

  // render html
  svgcontainer.innerHTML = htmlOutput;

}


/**
 * load font via opentype.js
 * decompress woff2 to truetype using
 * https://github.com/fontello/wawoff2
 * Based on yne's comment:
 * https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/issues/183#issuecomment-1147228025
 */
function loadFont(src, callback) {
  let buffer = {};
  let font = {};
  let ext;

  // is file
  if (src instanceof Object) {
    // get file extension to skip woff2 decompression
    let filename = src[0].name.split(".");
    ext = filename[filename.length - 1];
    buffer = src[0].arrayBuffer();
  }
  // is url
  else {
    let url = src.split(".");
    ext = url[url.length - 1];
    buffer = fetch(src).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
  }
  buffer.then((data) => {
    // decompress woff2
    if (ext === "woff2") {
      data = Uint8Array.from(Module.decompress(data)).buffer;
    }
    font = opentype.parse(data);
    callback(font);
  });
}
```

```css
        svg {
            height: 5em;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<h1>Convert fonts to SVG</h1>
<div class="svgcontainer" id="svgcontainer"></div>
<!-- required to parse woff2 fonts -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wawoff2@2.0.1/build/decompress_binding.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/opentype.js@latest/dist/opentype.min.js'></script>
```

### File Format support:

- woff
- truetype
- otf
- woff2

Opentype.js can't parse `woff2` files natively.
Fortunately github user [**yne** has found a workaround](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/issues/183#issuecomment-1147228025) employing [fontello's waWoff2 library](https://github.com/fontello/wawoff2).
That's why we need to load the additional waWoff2 script as well.

[Advanced Codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/XWZGVbZ)

Comment: Thank you for the CodePen, great resource that just works to get a SVG from a WOFF2 font file, unlike many other online converters I've tried!

Comment: @TechAurelian: My pleasure! Actually the pen still had a bug - it didn't really create a spritesheet using `<symbol>` and `<use>` elements. I fixed it and added some features (zip single icon svgs). If you still need the previous version you can go to [the previous version](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/GRYxQNd)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert them into svgs by yourself, they already provide you with the svg code for each and every icon they offer on their official website; You can download the equivalent svg code for an icon of your choice from the following link:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/svgs

There you will find svg code for all the Regular,Solid and Brands icons that you would see on the https://fontawesome.com/icons

Simply goto the https://fontawesome.com/icons choose an icon of your choice that you would like to use in your project and find the corresponding svg file from the list of files that you just downloaded from the above given link;
open the svg file in a code editor and copy the shape code from there which you can further consume!!!

HOW TO CONSUME? Well that's another topic....

P.S: Here is the link to the sprite file to download all the svg shapes in one file:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/sprites

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. This is useful information that pertains to font-awesome. I would also like to know how to pull an icon out of some another font icons, for example, font icons that was build by someone else (not font-awesome).

Comment: Almost every popular icon provider provides you with an svg shape code for each icon they offer; You are few searches behind; 
SVGS FOR ICONS OFFERED BY IONICONS
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/tree/master/src/svg    
AND SVGS FOR ICONS OFFERED BY LINEA
https://github.com/linea-io/Linea-Iconset
.

Comment: I would suggest you get your hands on the pro version of the font-awesome icons , there you will find almost every possible icon one would want to use in his/her project. the pro version comes along with svg files and svg sprites where you can easily trace the svg code for an icon of your choice! FURTHERMORE font-awesome is also recommended by Bootstrap

Comment: I built https://iconmeister.github.io/ because I needed to cherry pick from multiple iconsets and only wanted SVG for the icons I really used.