# How do download CSS Icon from website that is not an image i can right-click

Tags: css, web-scraping, icons

I'm trying to download the set icons associated with the different expansions of the game Netrunner. I can see the icons at https://netrunnerdb.com/en/sets, next to each set there is an icon. When i inspect it, it seems to just be a span with a CSS class with the icon name. My goal is to find or create SVGs of these icons, so if the website already has these in a vector format it would help me out a lot.

I cannot right click and save it, i cannot highlight it. So i'm not sure how the icon is being rendered. Is it a custom font the website is serving?

This is all i see when I inspect it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by Tim R: it's an icon font.

You can extract seperate svgs from the font using an icon generator like [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app).

1. download the svg font file
   `https://netrunnerdb.com/fonts/netrunner.svg`
   (Found in `@font-face` rule)
2. import it
   [image]
3. select glyphs/icons
4. export all icon

[image]

If there is no svg font file available, you can convert a woff2, woff or truetype to svg font  via a tool like [transfonter.](https://transfonter.org/) and convert this file via icomoon.

Alternatively, you can also directly convert a woff2, woff or ttr file using opentype.js as explained here ["How to convert font icon to .svg by myself?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187756/how-to-convert-font-icon-to-svg-by-myself/75836446#75836446)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it a custom font the website is serving?

Yes. Click on the `::before` in Developer Tools and you'll see:

```
.icon-flashpoint:before {    netrunnerfont.css:96
    content: "\e921";
}
```

Click on the stylesheet and you'll see:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'netrunner';
  src:  url('fonts/netrunner.eot?cmdd12');
  src:  url('fonts/netrunner.eot?cmdd12#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/netrunner.ttf?cmdd12') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/netrunner.woff?cmdd12') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/netrunner.svg?cmdd12#netrunner') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.icon {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'netrunner' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

...

.icon-flashpoint:before {
  content: "\e921";
}
```

Comment: thanks! i actually found the font but i'm not sure how to access the items... will ask another question