# Convert Glyph path to SVG

Tags: svg

I have the following glyph path:

```
<glyph glyph-name="right-nav-workflow" unicode="&#xe8c1;" d="M251 101c0 65 0 131 0 196 26 0 52 0 78 0 0 27 0 54 0 81-29 7-52 23-67 50-11 20-14 41-10 64 8 45 48 79 92 81 49 1 88-29 102-79 2 0 4 0 6 0 20 0 40 0 60 0 5 0 8 1 11 5 32 32 64 64 96 96 2 1 3 3 4 4 42-42 84-84 127-127-1 0-2-2-4-4-32-32-65-65-98-98-2-2-4-6-4-10 0-21 0-43 0-64 30-8 53-24 67-52 12-21 15-44 9-68-11-46-55-78-102-75-48 3-88 42-92 91-4 48 28 91 78 104 0 1 1 3 1 4 0 21 0 42 0 62 0 3-2 5-3 7-28 28-55 55-83 83-1 1-3 3-5 3-22 0-45 0-68 0-5-19-13-36-27-50-14-14-31-23-50-27 0-27 0-53 0-81 26 0 52 0 78 0 0-65 0-130 0-196-65 0-131 0-196 0z m157 156c-40 0-79 0-118 0 0-39 0-78 0-117 40 0 79 0 118 0 0 39 0 78 0 117z m275-58c0 33-26 59-59 59-32 0-59-26-59-59 0-33 27-59 60-59 32 0 58 26 58 59z m-334 216c33 0 59 27 59 59 0 33-26 59-59 59-33 0-59-26-59-59 0-33 26-59 59-59z m275-11c23 23 46 46 69 69-23 23-47 46-69 68-23-22-46-46-69-69 23-22 46-45 69-68z" horiz-adv-x="1000" />
```

How can I convert this into SVG? I tried to save it in a text file with svg extension but seems is not working.

Comment: It already is SVG, albeit an element that browsers don't support.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take the raw drawing data, put it in a path element, remove the glyph specific attributes, add an appropriate viewBox. Now you have something that works as an inline SVG. If you want to save it as a standalone SVG, then you need to add a name space declaration.

```html
<svg height="400px" width="400px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <path transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-650)" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" d="M251 101c0 65 0 131 0 196 26 0 52 0 78 0 0 27 0 54 0 81-29 7-52 23-67 50-11 20-14 41-10 64 8 45 48 79 92 81 49 1 88-29 102-79 2 0 4 0 6 0 20 0 40 0 60 0 5 0 8 1 11 5 32 32 64 64 96 96 2 1 3 3 4 4 42-42 84-84 127-127-1 0-2-2-4-4-32-32-65-65-98-98-2-2-4-6-4-10 0-21 0-43 0-64 30-8 53-24 67-52 12-21 15-44 9-68-11-46-55-78-102-75-48 3-88 42-92 91-4 48 28 91 78 104 0 1 1 3 1 4 0 21 0 42 0 62 0 3-2 5-3 7-28 28-55 55-83 83-1 1-3 3-5 3-22 0-45 0-68 0-5-19-13-36-27-50-14-14-31-23-50-27 0-27 0-53 0-81 26 0 52 0 78 0 0-65 0-130 0-196-65 0-131 0-196 0z m157 156c-40 0-79 0-118 0 0-39 0-78 0-117 40 0 79 0 118 0 0 39 0 78 0 117z m275-58c0 33-26 59-59 59-32 0-59-26-59-59 0-33 27-59 60-59 32 0 58 26 58 59z m-334 216c33 0 59 27 59 59 0 33-26 59-59 59-33 0-59-26-59-59 0-33 26-59 59-59z m275-11c23 23 46 46 69 69-23 23-47 46-69 68-23-22-46-46-69-69 23-22 46-45 69-68z"/>
  
</svg>
```

Update - Robert points out that the SVG Fonts spec has a y axis (0 on the bottom) that's inverted from the SVG norm (0 is the top) -> so you also need to flip the drawing along the x axis by using a scale (1,-1).

Comment: It will be [upside down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113478/extracting-svg-from-font-awesome) if you do that.

Comment: Added an appropriate scale and translate. (Learned something new - thanks Robert)

Comment: this will NOT keep colors, in case of colored empji.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example emoji glyph that has this problem? The emoji glyphs I find all have fill color specified internally.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Search for SVG repository

Especially, when you're dealing with icons.
Most icon libraries (e.g fontAwesome, Material UI etc.) also provide single SVG files or spritesheets.

### 2. Convert SVG fonts with an icon generator service

Although svg fonts are kind of deprecated - **not supported by Firefox or Chromium** – icon generators like [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) or [fontello](https://fontello.com/) can still use them as an import format.

1. import icons
2. select glyphs
3. export single svgs[image: icomoon app]

### 3. Convert with javaScript

The following conversion function works like this:

1. parse font metrics in like asccender `<font-face>` element – we'll need this for shifting the glyph path vertically
2. parse the `<glyph>` pathdata – I'm using [getPathData polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill)
3. Flip Y coordinates via custom `scaleAndShiftPathData()` helper and shift all glyphs vertically by the `ascent` attribute value

```js
let svgFont2Svg = parseSVGFont(svgFont);
document.body.append(svgFont2Svg)


function parseSVGFont(svgFont) {
  let isSVGFont = svgFont.querySelector("font") ? true : false;

  if (isSVGFont) {
    let ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    // get font metrics
    let fontFace = svgFont.querySelector("font-face");
    let unitsPerEm = +fontFace.getAttribute("units-per-em");
    let ascent = +fontFace.getAttribute("ascent");
    let descent = fontFace.getAttribute("descent")
      ? Math.abs(+fontFace.getAttribute("descent"))
      : 0;
    let glyphs = svgFont.querySelectorAll("glyph");
    let fontWrap = document.createElement("div");

    glyphs.forEach((glyph, i) => {
      let d = glyph.getAttribute("d");
      if (d) {
        // create glyph svg
        let glyphName = glyph.getAttribute("glyph-name");
        let glyphSvg = document.createElementNS(ns, "svg");
        let width = glyph.getAttribute("horiz-adv-x")
          ? +glyph.getAttribute("horiz-adv-x")
          : unitsPerEm;
        // glyphSvg.setAttribute('viewBox', [0, 0, width, unitsPerEm+(descent)].join(' '));
        glyphSvg.setAttribute(
          "viewBox",
          [0, 0, width, unitsPerEm - descent].join(" ")
        );
        glyphSvg.setAttribute("xmlns", ns);
        glyphSvg.id = glyphName;
        let path = document.createElementNS(ns, "path");
        path.setAttribute('d', d)
        let pathData = path.getPathData({normalize:true});
        
        // flip cartesian to svg coordinate system
        pathData = scaleAndShiftPathData(pathData, 1, -1, 0, ascent);

        //shift by ascender height
        offsetY = descent;
        //pathData = shiftPathData(pathData, 0, ascent);
        path.setPathData(pathData);
        glyphSvg.appendChild(path);
        fontWrap.appendChild(glyphSvg);
      }
    });
    return fontWrap;
  }
}


/**
 * scale pathData
 */
function scaleAndShiftPathData(pathData, scaleX=1, scaleY=1, shiftX=0, shiftY=0) {
  let pathDataScaled = [];
  pathData.forEach((com) => {
    let [type, values] = [com.type, com.values];
    let typeL = type.toLowerCase();
    let valuesL = values.length;
    let valsScaled = [];

    switch (typeL) {
      case "z":
        pathDataScaled.push(com);
        break;

      default:
        if (valuesL) {
          valsScaled = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2) {
            let x = values[i] * scaleX + shiftX;
            let y = values[i + 1] * scaleY + shiftY;
            valsScaled.push(x, y);
          }
          pathDataScaled.push({ type: type, values: valsScaled });
        }
    }
  });
  return pathDataScaled;
}
```

```css
svg{
  height:10em;
  width:auto;
  overflow: visible;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!-- svg font -->
<svg style="display:none" id="svgFont" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
<defs>
<font id="Poppins-Medium" horiz-adv-x="0" >
  <font-face 
    font-family="Poppins Medium"
    font-weight="500"
    font-stretch="normal"
    units-per-em="1000"
    panose-1="0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
    ascent="800"
    descent="-200"
    cap-height="696"
    bbox="0 -6 736 704"
    underline-thickness="50"
    underline-position="-150"
    unicode-range="U+0020-0047"
  />
<missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="500" 
d="M0 700h500v-700h-500v700zM420 650h-340l170 -255zM50 95l170 255l-170 255v-510zM450 95v510l-170 -255zM420 50l-170 255l-170 -255h340z" />
    <glyph glyph-name=".notdef" horiz-adv-x="500" 
d="M0 700h500v-700h-500v700zM420 650h-340l170 -255zM50 95l170 255l-170 255v-510zM450 95v510l-170 -255zM420 50l-170 255l-170 -255h340z" />
    <glyph glyph-name=".null" 
 />
    <glyph glyph-name="nonmarkingreturn" horiz-adv-x="333" 
 />
    <glyph glyph-name="NULL" 
 />
    <glyph glyph-name="space" unicode=" " horiz-adv-x="260" 
 />
    <glyph glyph-name="A" unicode="A" horiz-adv-x="697" 
d="M494 142h-291l-50 -142h-119l249 696h132l249 -696h-120zM462 235l-113 323l-114 -323h227z" />
    <glyph glyph-name="B" unicode="B" horiz-adv-x="630" 
d="M542 298q39 -49 39 -111q0 -53 -27.5 -95.5t-79.5 -67t-121 -24.5h-278v695h265q71 0 122 -24t77 -64.5t26 -90.5q0 -60 -32 -100t-86 -59q56 -10 95 -59zM189 403h141q56 0 87.5 25.5t31.5 73.5q0 47 -31.5 73.5t-87.5 26.5h-141v-199zM434 121q33 28 33 78q0 51 -35 81
t-93 30h-150v-217h154q58 0 91 28z" />
    <glyph glyph-name="C" unicode="C" horiz-adv-x="773" 
d="M84.5 532q47.5 81 129 126.5t178.5 45.5q111 0 197.5 -54.5t125.5 -154.5h-137q-27 55 -75 82t-111 27q-69 0 -123 -31t-84.5 -89t-30.5 -135t30.5 -135t84.5 -89.5t123 -31.5q63 0 111 27t75 82h137q-39 -100 -125.5 -154t-197.5 -54q-98 0 -179 45.5t-128.5 126.5
t-47.5 183t47.5 183z" />
    <glyph glyph-name="D" unicode="D" horiz-adv-x="709" 
d="M496.5 652.5q83.5 -42.5 129 -122t45.5 -185.5t-45.5 -184t-129 -119.5t-194.5 -41.5h-227v695h227q111 0 194.5 -42.5zM489 159q65 66 65 186q0 121 -65 189t-187 68h-113v-509h113q122 0 187 66z" />
    <glyph glyph-name="E" unicode="E" horiz-adv-x="524" 
d="M189 603v-204h240v-93h-240v-213h270v-93h-384v696h384v-93h-270z" />
    <glyph glyph-name="F" unicode="F" horiz-adv-x="515" 
d="M484 695v-93h-295v-205h230v-93h-230v-304h-114v695h409z" />
    <glyph glyph-name="G" unicode="G" horiz-adv-x="773" 
d="M578 495q-27 52 -75 78.5t-111 26.5q-69 0 -123 -31t-84.5 -88t-30.5 -132t30.5 -132.5t84.5 -88.5t123 -31q93 0 151 52t71 141h-261v91h383v-89q-11 -81 -57.5 -149t-121 -108.5t-165.5 -40.5q-98 0 -179 45.5t-128.5 126.5t-47.5 183t47.5 183t129 126.5t178.5 45.5
q111 0 197.5 -54.5t125.5 -154.5h-137z" />
  </font>
</defs></svg>

<h3>Icomoon output</h3>
<!-- Generated by IcoMoon.io -->
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="32" viewBox="0 0 25 32">
<title>C</title>
<path d="M2.704 8.576q1.52-2.592 4.128-4.048t5.712-1.456q3.552 0 6.32 1.744t4.016 4.944h-4.384q-0.864-1.76-2.4-2.624t-3.552-0.864q-2.208 0-3.936 0.992t-2.704 2.848-0.976 4.32 0.976 4.32 2.704 2.864 3.936 1.008q2.016 0 3.552-0.864t2.4-2.624h4.384q-1.248 3.2-4.016 4.928t-6.32 1.728q-3.136 0-5.728-1.456t-4.112-4.048-1.52-5.856 1.52-5.856z"></path>
</svg>

<h3>Custom output</h3>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@latest/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

### As a side note: Opentype SVG fonts ≠ SVG fonts

As mentioned SVG fonts are barely used anywhere due to lacking browser support.

[**Opentype SVG fonts**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/svg) are commonly used for rich colored **Emojis** - for instance ["Noto Color"](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji) as they support a variety of styling options like predefined color, gradients etc.

Both formats are often confused – the deprecated SVG fonts can't be used like Opentype SVG fonts.

A lot of font converters (like [transfonter](https://transfonter.org/)) still support a SVG output – this won't be an Opentype SVG font.

If you need to extract glyphs from these you might use a free tool like ["OpenType SVG Font Editor"](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/opentype-svg-font-editor/9NJ7K9JX60P1?hl=de-de&gl=de&rtc=1) (Windows only)

Answer (score 0):

Michael Mullany's solution won't preserve colors (e.g. in empjis).

One solution I found:
Print an internet page containing the glyph to a PDF,
import the PDF into inkscape, use "TEXT AS VECTORS",
crop the glyph, and then save as SVG