# Convert SVG fonts to SVG paths

Tags: svg, fonts

Is there any way to convert the single glyphs of a svg font into a svg path, so that i could use those shapes instead of the fonts in an application? Does any one know of any application or program which does such a thing?

Comment: SVG font data is an upside down path. What exactly is stopping you from using it?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113478/extracting-svg-from-font-awesome/18113524#18113524

Comment: Most of all because i am a newbie in SVG and Fonts matters, i don't know exactly how are they to be used. On Linux I can not install them as i normally install fonts, so i thought converting them into shapes would make it easier for me to use them in my application.

Comment: Are you talking about the old, and dead, SVG font concept (i.e. an actual SVG file) or are you talking about normal, modern SVG fonts (i.e. standard OpenType fonts, with SVG outline data rather than TTF/CFF/CFF2/Bitmap)?

Comment: See also ["Convert Glyph path to SVG"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696217/convert-glyph-path-to-svg)