# Convert Font Icons To SVG Icons With Vite

Tags: svg, icons, vite, icon-fonts

(Google) Font Icons are very handy to use during development (easy exchangable, scalable, recognizable, readable), while inline SVG icons are loaded faster and have no issues with automatic translators, which is important for production.

So I was hoping that there is a way using Vite to automatically convert Google Font icons to SVG icons on build/publish?

Comment: Most icon fonts also provide a svg repository (e.g. material icons, fontAwesome). So you should opt for an icon library that already supports both concepts. If you need to manually convert fonts to svg icons have a look at these posts ["How to convert font icon to .svg by myself?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187756/how-to-convert-font-icon-to-svg-by-myself/75836446#75836446), ["Convert Glyph path to SVG"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54696217/convert-glyph-path-to-svg/76631996#76631996)