# SVG path data from Font Awsome

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, font-awesome

I want to use exactly such an icon on my website -
https://fontawesome.com/icons/code
where to get path data? is it possible on Font Awsome without buying a pro version?

I mean attribute d
[image]

Comment: [This previous question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113478/extracting-svg-from-font-awesome) seems to have a good number of answers, including a [link to fontawesome's GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57872710/7053198).

Comment: its better instead of an image using code editor to show your example.

Answer (score 0):

Fontawesome has all SVGs in their Git repo: [code.svg](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/svgs/solid/code.svg?short_path=373914f).

Icons [are licensed](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) under [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) (you can use them for free, if you stick to the terms).