# Creating a simple Angular element using the Font Awesome SVG to reduce redundancy?

Tags: html, angular, svg, font-awesome

I'm looking at these links ([replacing FA with SVG](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1415/replacing-the-regular-font-awesome-4-with-the-svg-version-of-the-icons-to-optimize-loading-times), [extracting SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113478/extracting-svg-from-font-awesome)) to use the Font Awesome SVG code, instead of the Font Awesome library, as I only need ~25 icons. I'm assuming this will reduce my build file size?

**QUESTIONS** -

1. Am I violating any copyright or some other Font Awesome license by doing this?
2. Is there a way in Angular to take the SVG code and build it into a HTML element to reduce redundancy?

ex. replace this

```css
.fa-svg-icon {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-self: center;
    /* 
        Define a global color for the icons 
        In this case black
    */
    fill: #000;
}
/*
    Define the size of the default icons
*/
.fa-svg-icon svg {
    height:1em;
    width:1em;
}

/*
    Positionate the SVG correctly
*/
.fa-svg-icon.svg-baseline svg {
    top: .125em;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<span class="fa-svg-icon svg-baseline">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
    <path d="M570.69,236.27,512,184.44V48a16,16,0,0,0-16-16H432a16,16,0,0,0-16,16V99.67L314.78,10.3C308.5,4.61,296.53,0,288,0s-20.46,4.61-26.74,10.3l-256,226A18.27,18.27,0,0,0,0,248.2a18.64,18.64,0,0,0,4.09,10.71L25.5,282.7a21.14,21.14,0,0,0,12,5.3,21.67,21.67,0,0,0,10.69-4.11l15.9-14V480a32,32,0,0,0,32,32H480a32,32,0,0,0,32-32V269.88l15.91,14A21.94,21.94,0,0,0,538.63,288a20.89,20.89,0,0,0,11.87-5.31l21.41-23.81A21.64,21.64,0,0,0,576,248.19,21,21,0,0,0,570.69,236.27ZM288,176a64,64,0,1,1-64,64A64,64,0,0,1,288,176ZM400,448H176a16,16,0,0,1-16-16,96,96,0,0,1,96-96h64a96,96,0,0,1,96,96A16,16,0,0,1,400,448Z"/>
  </svg>
</span>
```

With something like this

```html
<SpecialIcon class="fa-svg-icon svg-baseline"></SpecialIcon>
```

Comment: Mabe this will help you in transforming your SVG icons into fonts that you can use as classes. https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfont

Comment: Hi Pankaj, have you used this or did you just Google it?

Comment: We use it in our project. It basically  converts all your svg assets into fonts. You need to run this script each time you add a new font.

Comment: Hi. Do you know what the difference would be between this npm package and creating a custom Angular element with the SVG? Pro's, Con's, etc?

Comment: The webfont approach is useful if you have more than 25 icon assets. For only a few, adding them in a single component and switching between the SVGs is useful.

Comment: See https//iconmeister.github.io

Comment: @user1186050 Added the answer for custom element solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 2:**

You can create a custom component in Angular to reduce redundancy by taking in icon name as input:

**Icon Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'SpecialIcon',
  templateUrl: './SpecialIcon.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./SpecialIcon.component.scss']
})
export class IconComponent {
  @Input() iconName=''; // Take the icon name as input to this component
  constructor() { }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="iconName">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'baseline'">
    <span class="fa-svg-icon svg-baseline">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
        <path d="M570.69,236.27,512,184.44V48a16,16,0,0,0-16-16H432a16,16,0,0,0-16,16V99.67L314.78,10.3C308.5,4.61,296.53,0,288,0s-20.46,4.61-26.74,10.3l-256,226A18.27,18.27,0,0,0,0,248.2a18.64,18.64,0,0,0,4.09,10.71L25.5,282.7a21.14,21.14,0,0,0,12,5.3,21.67,21.67,0,0,0,10.69-4.11l15.9-14V480a32,32,0,0,0,32,32H480a32,32,0,0,0,32-32V269.88l15.91,14A21.94,21.94,0,0,0,538.63,288a20.89,20.89,0,0,0,11.87-5.31l21.41-23.81A21.64,21.64,0,0,0,576,248.19,21,21,0,0,0,570.69,236.27ZM288,176a64,64,0,1,1-64,64A64,64,0,0,1,288,176ZM400,448H176a16,16,0,0,1-16-16,96,96,0,0,1,96-96h64a96,96,0,0,1,96,96A16,16,0,0,1,400,448Z"/>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </ng-container>
<!--For every svg, you will have to add in a switch case-->
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'other'">
    <span class="fa-svg-icon svg-other">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
        <path d="M570.69,236.27,512,184.44V48a16,16,0,0,0-16-16H432a16,16,0,0,0-16,16V99.67L314.78,10.3C308.5,4.61,296.53,0,288,0s-20.46,4.61-26.74,10.3l-256,226A18.27,18.27,0,0,0,0,248.2a18.64,18.64,0,0,0,4.09,10.71L25.5,282.7a21.14,21.14,0,0,0,12,5.3,21.67,21.67,0,0,0,10.69-4.11l15.9-14V480a32,32,0,0,0,32,32H480a32,32,0,0,0,32-32V269.88l15.91,14A21.94,21.94,0,0,0,538.63,288a20.89,20.89,0,0,0,11.87-5.31l21.41-23.81A21.64,21.64,0,0,0,576,248.19,21,21,0,0,0,570.69,236.27ZM288,176a64,64,0,1,1-64,64A64,64,0,0,1,288,176ZM400,448H176a16,16,0,0,1-16-16,96,96,0,0,1,96-96h64a96,96,0,0,1,96,96A16,16,0,0,1,400,448Z"/>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </ng-container> 
<!--Default case is optional though. -->
  <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
    <span class="fa-svg-icon svg-default">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
        <path d="M570.69,236.27,512,184.44V48a16,16,0,0,0-16-16H432a16,16,0,0,0-16,16V99.67L314.78,10.3C308.5,4.61,296.53,0,288,0s-20.46,4.61-26.74,10.3l-256,226A18.27,18.27,0,0,0,0,248.2a18.64,18.64,0,0,0,4.09,10.71L25.5,282.7a21.14,21.14,0,0,0,12,5.3,21.67,21.67,0,0,0,10.69-4.11l15.9-14V480a32,32,0,0,0,32,32H480a32,32,0,0,0,32-32V269.88l15.91,14A21.94,21.94,0,0,0,538.63,288a20.89,20.89,0,0,0,11.87-5.31l21.41-23.81A21.64,21.64,0,0,0,576,248.19,21,21,0,0,0,570.69,236.27ZM288,176a64,64,0,1,1-64,64A64,64,0,0,1,288,176ZM400,448H176a16,16,0,0,1-16-16,96,96,0,0,1,96-96h64a96,96,0,0,1,96,96A16,16,0,0,1,400,448Z"/>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </ng-container> 
</ng-container>
```

CSS: Place all your CSS in `SpecialIcon.component.scss` file. You can have separate CSS for each icon in this file.

```
/*
    For each icon, you can have different stylings
*/
.fa-svg-icon.svg-baseline svg {
    top: .125em;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Usage:** Pass in the icon name to the component

```
<SpecialIcon [iconName]="'baseline'"></SpecialIcon >
```

**Question 1:** The official website says that its open source, so you can use it.
https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/license/

> Font Awesome is fully open source and is GPL friendly. You can use it
> for commercial projects, open source projects, or really just about
> whatever you want.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this help!